# Micro-frontend consumed by another (same repository) : Shared module is not available for eager consumption

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Hope you're doing fine.

I am currently working on a project which is composed (for now) of 2 MFEs, one with a button and a text, the other one is an Icon (very basic ...)

I actually succeed to fetch the Icon in the first one, I can see it in the browser's Network calls (check the pic down there) but I have the following error in the console :

**`main.js:3866 Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/jsx-runtime/react/jsx-runtime?37fb`**

[image]

The thing is that in my Webpack file I already tried with the eager props set to false. Nothing changed ...

Here is the Webpack from the consumer part :

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const { NodeFederationPlugin, StreamingTargetPlugin } = require('@module-federation/node');
const deps = require('../package.json').dependencies;

const getSharedDeps = deps => {
    const shared = [...Object.keys(deps), 'react/jsx-runtime', 'react-dom/client'];

    return shared.reduce((shared, moduleName) => {
        shared[moduleName] = {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps[moduleName],
            strictVersion: false,
        };

        return shared;
    }, {});
};

const name = 'basicPortal';
const sharedDeps = getSharedDeps(deps);
const exposed = { './BasicPortal': './src/index.ts' };
const remoteUrls = { bookmark: 'bookmark@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js' };

module.exports = {
    client: new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name,
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: exposed,
        remotes: remoteUrls,
        shared: sharedDeps,
    }),
    server: [
        new NodeFederationPlugin({
            name,
            library: { type: 'commonjs2' },
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: exposed,
            remotes: remoteUrls,
            shared: sharedDeps,
        }),
        new StreamingTargetPlugin({
            name,
            library: { type: 'commonjs2' },
            exposes: exposed,
            remotes: remoteUrls,
        }),
    ],
};
```

and there is the consumed one :

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const { NodeFederationPlugin, StreamingTargetPlugin } = require('@module-federation/node');
const deps = require('../package.json').dependencies;

const getSharedDeps = deps => {
    const shared = [...Object.keys(deps), 'react/jsx-runtime', 'react-dom/client'];

    return shared.reduce((shared, moduleName) => {
        shared[moduleName] = {
            eager: false,
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps[moduleName],
            strictVersion: false,
        };

        return shared;
    }, {});
};

const name = 'bookmark';
const sharedDeps = getSharedDeps(deps);
const exposed = { './Bookmarkheart': './src/index.ts' };

module.exports = {
    client: new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name,
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: exposed,
        shared: sharedDeps,
    }),
    server: [
        new NodeFederationPlugin({
            name,
            library: { type: 'commonjs2' },
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: exposed,
            shared: sharedDeps,
        }),
        new StreamingTargetPlugin({
            name,
            library: { type: 'commonjs2' },
            exposes: exposed,
        }),
    ],
};
```

If you need, following how I consume the Mfe :

```
//@ts-ignore: next-line
    const BookmarkHeart = lazy(() => import("bookmark/Bookmarkheart"));
...
```

If you've already ran across this error and feel familiar with it, I'd appreciate your help (like, so much) ! Thank you for your time and happy coding :)

I tried switching both eagers to true, false. Also tried to change the exposed content and so on ...